# A Pushout diagram is also a pullback diagram in specific cases in Category of Graphs and Morphisms

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

Suppose I have the following pushout diagram in the category of [multi graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) and morphism ($A_1 \rightarrow A_2 \leftarrow B_2$ is pushout of $A_1 \leftarrow B_1 \rightarrow B_2$ ). Suppose that I know $j'$ is an inclusion mapping.

[image]

> **Question 1:** It seems that $j$ should be an inclusion mapping as well. Am I right? Why?
>
> **Question2:**  It seems the above diagram should be also a pullback (that is,  $A_1 \leftarrow B_1 \rightarrow B_2$ should be  pullback of $A_1 \rightarrow A_2 \leftarrow B_2$. Am I right? Why?

Comment: Can you describe what are the objects and what are the morphisms more explicitly?

Comment: The objects are graphs (finite graphs) and morphisms are graph morphisms as I wrote in the question content.

Comment: I think this category is equivalent to a presheaf category. In which case all limits and colimits are constructed pointwise in Set. Thus 1 would be true and 2 false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly which category of graphs you're talking about, but the following should be valid for all of them:

Question 1: No, $j$ need not be an inclusion in general.  For instance, if $B_1$ is a discrete graph with two vertices and $i$ and $j$ are both constant maps, then $A_2$ is just the wedge sum of $A_1$ and $B_2$, joined at the images of $i$ and $j$.  The map $A_1\to A_2$ is then injective, but $j$ is not.  More generally, whenever $j$ fails to be injective but $i$ *also* fails to be injective in the same way, this will not prevent $j'$ from being injective.

Question 2: No, with the same counterexample.  In that example, the pullback would just be a single vertex.